# android dialog close button

Tags: android

I have an activity and I have set as a dialog using

```
<activity android:name=".ChangeUserImageActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
```

How can I create a close button at the top right? Currently, my layout is as follows and I am using absolute layout...

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/closebtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="260px"
    android:layout_y="5px"
    android:text="X"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:onClick="close_click"
    />
```

Comment: can you show your layout xml here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your current layout so the parent is a `RelativeLayout` and then your `Button` will look like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/closebtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="X"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:onClick="close_click"
    />
```

And of course you'll have to modify your current layout to use the `RelativeLayout`(the layout you didn't added to your question)